# Setting Text color for CCTexture2d initWithString

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a CCTexture2d using initWithString. But how do I set the color for this text?

CCTexture2D* texture  = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithString:labeltext fontName:@"Carlisle" fontSize:18];

(Cocos2d 99.5, XCode 3.2.5 BaseSDK 4.2 Objective-C, Deployent OS 3.1.3)

Comment: Using CCLabelTTF instead, and then using the texture it creates. Can use the label.color property to change the colors. The question remains, but since I have a workaround it has a low priority...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague found out a solution that works for me:

```
unsigned long color = 0xFFFF0000;
CCSprite* sprite = <<get your sprite here>>;
sprite.color      = ccc3(GetR(color), GetG(color), GetB(color));
```

It sets the color for the sprite, not the texture, so it is not exactly what I was looking for, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

do u mean something like [texture setColor:someColor];
where someColor is a ccColor3B

Comment: setColor does not seem to be a valid function of CCTexture2d... I tried your suggestion, but got: 'CCTexture2D' may not respond to '-setColor:'

Comment: strange it worked for me. maybe http://lukehatcher.com/post/449164972/coloring-sprites-with-cocos2d-iphone is what your after

Comment: Thanks for the link. It might be a solution. I'll dive back into it when I have some more time. The problem is not urgent enough now.